# Android app getting removed from memory

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, android-memory

I have the following structure in my app:

Landing activity = Activity Landing, which after signin, goes to Main Activity

When I run the app using Android Studio, I can see the app in the Android screen with the package name. After I am in the MainActivity, and then press home and open several other apps (around 15 of them) to use up memory, I can see that the app gets removed from the Android panel in Android studio (as highlighted in the picture attached)

I log all the Activity Lifecycle event functions in both Landing and Main activity (including onDestroy()), however I dont see any of these being called in the logs when Android OS silently takes out my app from memory.

Also strangely even after the app is no longer in memory, when I press the app icon on home screen, it still starts the MainActivity automatically. How is the Landing Activity being skipped (although that is the LAUNCHER as defined in AndroidManifest)?

How can I ensure a callback function when OS deletes my app from memory to do housekeeping stuff?

```
                                              +------> Strangely shows up MainActivity and not Landing
                                              |                                                       
                                              +                                                       
+--------------------+              Find my app icon on home screen and press it                      
|                    |                                                                                
|     ActivityLanding|                       ^                                                        
|                    |                       |                                                        
+--------+-----------+                       |                                                        
         |                                   +                                                        
         |                           Open around 15 other apps                                        
         |                             Deplete memory                                                 
         |                                                                                            
         |                                                                                            
         |                                 ^                                                          
         |                                 |                                                          
         |                                 +                                                          
 +------+v-----------+                                                                                
 |  ActivityMain     | +--------> Press Home on phone                                                 
 |                   |                                                                                
 +-------------------+
```

[image]

Comment: `onpause()` and `onStop()` is already called,when you started opening other apps, and alos well ,that means it was never killed was it?

Comment: onPause() onStop() is where you do the house keeping.

Comment: I can confirm the app removal without triggering onPause / onStop.